# How do I remove a specific item in a list based on its position

Tags: c++, list, oop

Example: I have a class of myClass which consists of 3 private attributes:

1. string itemName
2. float amount
3. string date

Then I create a list of `myClass`

```
list<myClass> mytemp;
```

In my `mytemp` I store a few items inside:

> [ itemName ] [ amount ] [ date ]
>
> 1. myproductA 10 011214
> 2. myproductB 20 010115
> 3. myproductC 30 020115
> 4. myproductD 40 040115

I would like to delete myproductC

I currently have:

```
list<myClass>::iterator p=mytemp.begin();

//productC would be list(3)

p++; p++; p++;

//therefore remove:

mytemp.remove(p);
```

Am I right to say that?
However `p` is an iterator, but `list::remove` wants a value.

How do I overcome this problem?

Comment: use `std::advance(mytemp, 3)` instead of incrementing the iterator 3 times.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: `mytemp` is the `list` itself. Pass `p` instead of `mytemp`. And he wants to remove the 3rd item, so use `2` instead of `3` (`p` is initially pointing at the 1st item). `std::advance(p, 2)`

Comment: Yes, should be `std::advance(p,2)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that the target element in the list is the third element then instead of this code

```
list<myClass>::iterator p=mytemp.begin();

//productC would be list(3)

p++; p++; p++;

//therefore remove:

mytemp.remove(p);
```

You can replace it with this, if you are using C++11 or later:

```
mytemp.erase( std::next( mytemp.begin(), 2 ) );
```

Or this if you are using an older version:

```
list<myClass>::iterator p = mytemp.begin();
std::advance( p, 2 );
mytemp.erase( p );
```

To use `std::next()` or `std::advance()`, you need `#include <iterator>`.

As for the method `remove()`, it removes all elements of the `list` that are equal to a given value.

Comment: `std::next()` is new in C++11.  For older versions, you can use `std::advance()` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::list::erase()` [method](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/erase).